# UITabBarController deallocating views after memory warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uitabbarcontroller

I'm creating an app using a UITabBarController as the main form of navigation, having never done this before I've ran into a little bit of an issue.

On two of the four tabs, the view controllers held drill down using a standard navigation controller and browse through categories and then into items, the categories and items have quite a few images.

After a few minutes of using my app (down to the item stage where a scrollview of 4 320x460 images is used) i get..

```
Received memory warning. Level=1
```

This then deallocate's all of the view's currently held in my UITabBarController, and when I click the tabs, i am presented with only white screens.

When using images, I am trying to use..

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

..as much as possible, as far as i'm aware, that is 'memory managed', and should dealloc correctly.

The memory issue I believe is merely being caused by 4 large images being loaded into memory, this is a requirement of my app. The tab's dissapearing isn't :/

Any ideas/guidance?

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the value of viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload. Also you should always by any means get rid of auto-release pool and do manual retain / release count management. In your case it's rather easy: UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]]; [self.view addSubview:imageView]; [imageView release];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. When your app receives a memory warning, all view controllers that are not currently visible will unload their views. You have to be prepared for that. When the user reopens a tab that was unloaded, the view controller reloads the view and calls `-viewDidLoad` again where you should do your view setup.

Comment: Thank you, when I know the answer, it's simple!, thanks for helping me to see the wood from the tree's guys.

Comment: What if the view was loaded from a XIB?  And what about all of the objects that you may have allocated in the previous call to viewDidLoad?  If you re-do all of those allocations, you're going to leak all of the previous instances.

Comment: @Oscar: NIB or not doesn't make a difference. The process is exactly the same. In order to not waste or leak memory, you have to release everything you allocated/retained in `viewDidLoad` in the `viewDidUnload` method. The documentation describes this in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Ole. The mystery in our case is why loadView is not reloading the view from its XIB, and instead leaving us with a blank white screen.

Answer (score 1):

Ole gave a decent explanation. One thing though, if your off-screen view controller's view gets unloaded, you should setup it again in the `-loadView`. 
This method gets called to set up your view hierarchy, then `-viewDidLoad` gets called, to signal that the view is ready.
If you implement it in `-viewDidLoad`, you would have an empty view loaded (UIViewController `-loadView`), then replaced (with your `-viewDidLoad` code), causing a flicker.

An even more elaborate explanation about loading your views is available here: http://myok12.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/custom-uiviewcontrollers-their-views-and-their-memory-management/

Comment: You don't override loadView if the screen is loaded from a XIB, though.